# Python: Creating a multiple choice quiz

Tags: python, function, loops

I'm trying to write a program in python that will first, ask the user to choose a sport (football, tennis, golf or badminton) and then pick either easy, medium or hard. The program should then ask the user 5 questions about the sport with 4 choices if the user has picked 'easy', 6 if the user has picked 'medium' and 8 if the user has picked 'hard'.

Can anyone help me start this off?

Comment: how is this related to java?

Comment: It's not, but a lot of java programmers can also program in python.

Comment: That's not a reason to tag this post with Java

Comment: Alright, sorry.

Comment: Also, you need to show the attempts that you have made in solving this problem. Currently you are asking people to write some code for you from scratch, which is not how this site works.

Comment: I'll update my post in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

There's a Python library called `tkinter` which you could use for this. A basic design for the selection process is below:

```
from tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.x = IntVar()
        self.y = IntVar()
        self.frame = Frame(root)
        self.frame.pack()
        self.sport = [("football", 0), ("tennis", 1), ("golf", 2), ("badminton", 3)]
        self.diff = [("easy", 0), ("medium", 1), ("hard", 2)]
        for i, c in self.sport:
            Radiobutton(self.frame, text=i, variable=self.x, value=c, indicatoron=0).pack(anchor="w", fill="both", expand=True)
        for i, c in self.diff:
            Radiobutton(self.frame, text=i, variable=self.y, value=c, indicatoron=0).pack(anchor="w", fill="both", expand=True)
        Button(self.frame, text="Ok", command=self.start).pack(anchor="w", fill="both", expand=True)
    def start(self):
        print("questions: "+self.sport[self.x.get()][0]+", "+"difficulty: "+self.diff[self.y.get()][0])


root = Tk()
App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

From there you'd need to start your loop and cycle through a selection of questions which would most likely be contained in some form of nested iterable.

You could have something like:

```
[[(fb question 1, [list of answers]), ...], [(tennis question 1, [list of answers]), ...], ...]
```

---

On a side note, Stack Overflow is not a free programming service, nor a resource for creating homework assignments for you. We are more than happy to help you out with problems if you get stuck at some point in your development cycle, but will not write the program for you.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I don't need a graphical user interface, I just need a simple program :)

Comment: @AliceWilliams You don't what?

Comment: It was wrong of me to post such a brief question, apologies! I'll consider this in future, however, it's a good idea.

Comment: It's fine, I only came across your question as it was in the "First Post" queue. The queue is designed to show you users who may need some help with getting in to the community. Please feel free to contact me if you need anything.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll contact you shortly with a more detailed description of what I'm looking for.

Comment: Cool, I'm going to remove the contact part from my question as it's off topic, but my address is still on my profile